# YTPlayer vídeo de fondo de no reproduce automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He integrado el complemento https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer, siguiendo los ejemplos de documentación y no he podido iniciar el video automáticamente, el usuario debe hacer clic para reproducirlo.

Hay una manera de simular este clic, o alguna solución para que el video comience a cargarse sin ninguna acción del usuario.

> **Full code:** https://jsfiddle.net/py7bkox3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="video"></div>
<div id="ctn">
  <h1>TITLE EXAMPLE</h1>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// When the document is ready
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Initialize YouTube player
  $("#video").YTPlayer({
    // URL of the YouTube video
    videoURL:'https://youtu.be/BsekcY04xvQ',
    // If you want it as background of your website
    // or of an element e.g #elementId
    containment: "#ctn",
    autoplay: true,
    controls: 0,
    mute: true,
    startAt: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    // Hide YouTube Controls
    showControls: false,
    onReady: function(){
    },
    onError: function(err){
      console.log("An error ocurred", err);
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#ctn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 250px 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pagina de la api de youtube https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es hay un ejemplo que puedes adaptar para poner un video de fondo.

Así se veria con el video de tu pregunta:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <style type="text/css">

            #ctn {
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 250px 0 !important;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #player{
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
            }

        </style>
        <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
            <div id="ctn">
                <h1>TITLE EXAMPLE</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="player"></div>


            <script>
            // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
            var tag = document.createElement('script');

            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
            //    after the API code downloads.
            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: 'BsekcY04xvQ',
                    playerVars:{
                        autoplay: 1,
                        controls: 0,
                        rel: 0,
                        fs: 0,
                        mute: 1,
                        showinfo: 0
                    },
                });
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Puedes probar este código en tu local para ver como funciona.

Para la configuración del video debes pasarle este objeto para habilitar la reproduccón automatica y otras opciones como no mostrar los botones, silenciar el video, etc.

```
playerVars:{
  autoplay: 1,
  controls: 0,
  rel: 0,
  fs: 0,
  mute: 1,
  showinfo: 0
},
```

Puedes ver la lista de parametros en este link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

con eso ya puedes reproducir automaticamente el video de fondo.